# Issue with logout in cas

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, cas

I am building applications using spring where I have implemented spring security.

I have multiple application, to combine them I am using cas.

[image: Flow of cas]

In all project there is a "Log Out" option along with Gate Way project.

**So my question is** when I am clicking on logout only current project session is getting invalidate not from all. So how I can solve this issue.

**What is issue** Suppose user1 logged in and he logged out from Project 1. After that user2 logged in even I am getting user1 information in Gate Way project, once I am redirecting to Project1 I am getting correct information . Same thing if I am logging out from Gate Way project in this project only I am getting logged in user information and in other projects I am getting previous logged in user information.

How to solve this issue I have tried lot of thing but I am not getting any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement CAS single sign out where when a request is issued to the cas log out end point and if you have single log out enables, cas can reach out to all other applications that it currently has a session with and it will attempt to log the user out from all those sessions

Comment: how to implement CAS single sign out can you tell me in brief?@Misagh Moayyed

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed this issue manually not CAS supplied.

onclick of logot instead of calling CAS I am calling a method of respective application. there manuall I am doing session.invalidate(), and through rest service I am calling all logout methods of other application. There also I am doing same operation i.e. session.invalidate(). Finally I am redirecting to Gate Way project's logout method same work here also. At last it redirects me to cas loggin page.